# AWS Amplify database options

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, cloud, orientdb, aws-amplify

I am considering using AWS Amplify to create a backend for my app(s). I was hoping to use OrientDB which I have set up on an EC2, but all the examples and tutorials for Amplify only mention DynamoDB. Before I spend a lot of time learning how to use Amplify, is it possible to connect to any type of DB that can be installed on an EC2, or is DynamoDB all that is available?

Comment: You may look into AWS AppSync to front your database. AWS Amplify has support for AWS AppSync. For further help you may post in https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

After `amplify init` and `amplify add host`

Run `amplify add api`

- Choose **REST**
- Choose **Create a new Lambda function**
- **Don't choose** *CRUD function for Amazon DynamoDB table*
- Choose **Serverless express function (Integration with Amazon API Gateway)**

At your project **./amplify/backend/function**, you’ll see your lambda express. And then you can connect to any database you want.
Just need to input the connecting DB code.

Answer (score 4):

Amplify is at the moment tied to dynamoDB in a very strong way. But you can use graphQL queries sent to AppSync (the backend layer of amplify) [to trigger lambda functions](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql?sdk=android#add-a-custom-resolver-that-targets-an-aws-lambda-function). From there you can target any type of database you want